# Throwing dice vs. Poisson

Tags: probability

Suppose that we throw dice as long as we get  either 2 or 3 (so the chance of getting that is $p=1/3$). Okay, I want to know what is the probability that we will be throwing dice exactly $k$ times to achieve our goal. Normally I'd use Bernoulli scheme but since the number of occasions is not known, I will use Poisson instead to get

$$\frac{e^{-2/3} (\tfrac{2}{3})^k}{k!}.$$

Is that right? What if I just insist that $k$ is odd?

EDIT:  angryavian is right. For $k$ even, we just sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X = 2k-1)$, where $X$ has geometric distribution with parameter $1/3$.

Comment: You probably want the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable, equal to 1 if the die shows 2 or 3 on the $i$-th throw, and zero if it shows neither 2 nor 3. The event of interest is 
$$
 \mathcal{E}_k =  \{ X_1 = 0, \ldots, X_{k-1}=0, X_k=1 \}
$$
Given that $\{X_i\}$ are independent identically distributed Bernoulli random variables, the probability of the event equals the product of individual probabilities:
$$
  \Pr\left(\mathcal{E}_k\right) = \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \Pr(X_i=0) \cdot \Pr(X_k=1) = (1-p)^{k-1} p
$$
This is known of [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).